# Http GET request with parameters - Java

Tags: java

I need to create a java code that sends an Http GET request with the required parameter to get a response, or else I get an information message that is missing the parameter. In the moment I have the second option.

Why my DataOutputStream not write the parameters in my request?

Look the code:

```
public class ClienteWebService {
String URL_WEBSERVICE = "http://seat.ind.br/processo-seletivo/2018/01/desafio.php";
String nome = "Leonardo Rodrigues Torres";


public String getInformacoes() {

    StringBuilder urlParametros = new StringBuilder();
    urlParametros.append("nome=").append(nome);

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(URL_WEBSERVICE);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParametros.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        return response.toString();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder urlParametros = new StringBuilder();`
 `urlParametros.append("?nome=").append(nome);`

`URL_WEBSERVICE=URL_WEBSERVICE+urlParametros.toString()'
assuming there is only one parameter `nome`

Comment: if I concatenate URL_WEBSERVICE=URL_WEBSERVICE+urlParametros.toString() the connection fails, and i get the error: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://seat.ind.br/processo-seletivo/2018/01/desafio.php?nome=Leonardo Torres

Comment: Did you check the final `URL_WEBSERVICE`. If its `seat.ind.br/processo-seletivo/2018/01/desafio.php?nome=Leonardo` then there is issue with your code. Check your calling method.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you should b using `DataOutputStream` here. `DataOutputStream` is for a Java-specific, XDR-like data serialization protocol.

Comment: The problem was a blank space in the URL! when i erased it worked.